# How do I merge data from two tables in a single database call into the same columns?

Tags: sql, merge

If I run the two statements in batch will they return one table to two to my sqlcommand object with the data merged.  What I am trying to do is optimize a search by searching twice, the first time on one set of data and then a second on another.  They have the same fields and I’d like to have all the records from both tables show and be added to each other.  I need this so that I can sort the data between both sets of data but short of writing a stored procedure I can’t think of a way of doing this.

Eg. Table 1 has columns A and B, Table 2 has these same columns but different data source.  I then wan to merge them so that if a only exists in one column it is added to the result set and if both exist it eh tables the column B will be summed between the two.

Please note that this is not the same as a full outer join operation as that does not merge the data.

**[EDIT]**

Here's what the code looks like:

```
Select * From
 (Select ID,COUNT(*) AS Count From [Table1]) as T1
     full outer join
 (Select ID,COUNT(*) AS Count From [Table2]) as T2
     on t1.ID = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly:

```
select table1.a, table1.b
from table1
where table1.a not in (select a from table2)
union all
select table1.a, table1.b+table2.b as b
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.a = table2.a
```

edit: perhaps you would benefit from unioning the tables *before* counting.  e.g.

```
select id, count() as count from
(select id from table1
 union all
 select id from table2)
```

Comment: Both good methods.  I already did the second but I appreciate the example) I did a group by fro the second and summed the two columns. Works like a charm.

Comment: Although the second method should only use a union not a union all as it misses some of hte data.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for UNION?

IE:

```
SELECT A, B FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT A, B FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand completely but you seem to be asking about a UNION

```
SELECT A,B
FROM tableX
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B
FROM tableY
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it, you would go:

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE3 FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

Provided both tables have the same columns

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this, but I am not sure I am understanding your language correctly.

```
select id, sum(count) as count
from (
    select id, count() as count
    from table1
    union all
    select id, count() as count
    from table2
) a
group by id
```